# Adding spectra over different frequency ranges

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft

I think I have a slightly unusual question regarding combining two spectra that I cannot figure out! I want to calculate the fft of a time dependent function f(t), this function can be separated into two parts, f(t) = f_1(t) + f_2(t). f_1(t) is a slowly varying function (evolves on a nanosecond timescale), and f_2(t) is changes on a very fast (sub-picosecond) timescale.

It seems computationally expensive/crazy to evaluate f(t) with sub-picosecond time steps, given that f_2(t) reaches a constant value very quickly. However, it is quite easy to take the fft of f_1 and f_2 independently, unfortunately I can't figure out how to add these functions at the end. Is there a smart way of combing f_1(w) + f_2(w), given f_1 and f_2 have different frequency ranges?